# Folder won't delete from Trash for "Can't delete "_ImageItems" because its pathname is too long"

Tags: macos, trash

I'm trying to empty my trash on my iMac.  When I do, I can detete everything but 1 folder.  The one folder seems to reference itself infinitely.  Each time I click on the expander chevron, I get another folder of the same name with the same date.  When I created _ImageItems, there was only one level.

I've attached some screen clips[image: Too Long Error].

[image: Apparently infinitely recursive folders]

Answer (score 21):

For those who're using El Capitan or later version of macOS - simply using the command given in previous answers will return a warning that there were no matches found.

What you need to do instead is to pass paths of items in the Bin **explicitly** to the command. You can do that like this;

1. Open the Terminal.
2. Type in `sudo rm -rfv`  (don't forget the space!)
3. Open the Bin.
4. Select all items from the Bin and move them to the Terminal.
5. Run the command and enter your password.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: I wish i could vote this answer 100 times. Thank you very much @Nikola Stojakovic

Comment: I got this error 'zsh: permission denied' in mac m1 pro

Comment: This worked. Just that the instructions weren't super clear. After dragging from bin to terminal and see the path to the folder, ultimately I had to do: `sudo rm -rfv <path_of_folder_to_delete>`

Comment: worked for me following those steps but typing `rm -R` instead of `rm -rfv`

Comment: @Honey How is that different than what I said above?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the command line in the terminal.

```
rm -rvf ~/.Trash/*
```

For completeness sake the options here from the **rm** man page:

```
-f  Attempt to remove the files without prompting for confirmation,
     regardless of the file's permissions.  If the file does not exist,
     do not display a diagnostic message or modify the exit status to
     reflect an error.  The -f option overrides any previous -i
     options.

-R[-r]  Attempt to remove the file hierarchy rooted in each file argument.
         The -R option implies the -d option.  If the -i option is speci-
         fied, the user is prompted for confirmation before each direc-
         tory's contents are processed (as well as before the attempt is
         made to remove the directory).  If the user does not respond
         affirmatively, the file hierarchy rooted in that directory is
         skipped.

 -v   Be verbose when deleting files, showing them as they are removed.
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I tried this solution, but it doesn't seem to empty the trash.  Neither the recursive folder nor other items.  When I use `iMac:~ <user>$ ls -ltra ~/.Trash
ls: .Trash: Operation not permitted
iMac:~ <user>$ ls -ltra ~/.Trash/*
ls: /Users/<user>/.Trash/*: No such file or directory
iMac:~ <user>$ ls -ltra ~/.Trash/
ls: : Operation not permitted`
When I use "Get info" I get CloudDocs/.Trash

Comment: I tried this code but it throws an error saying ```zsh: no matches found: /Users/mahdifaraji/.Trash/*```

Answer (score 4):

Just move the folder out of trash and then use rm -rf on the folder.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. I had accidentally created an extremely long directory path when building a script that recursively moves/creates directories within itself.

Answer (score 1):

Sudo‘ing worked for me, after giving full hard disc access to Terminal in Settings/Security:

```
sudo rm -rvf ~/.Trash
```

Comment: It would be better if you also described if you had pretty much the same problem or only something somewhat similar, if any.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me after making sure terminal has full access on the disk :

```
rm -rvf ~/.Trash
```

Comment: The suggestion is already posted above.  It doesn't work as the files are stored elsewhere that I don't have access and continue to re-appear in the trash.